# Mysql Query with HTML checkboxes and PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Is anyone able to point me to a resource that can tell me how to use checkboxes to populate a query?

For example you have 3 different qualifications:

```
olevel
alevel
gcse
```

On the HTML form we have three checkboxes so the user can search by any combination of the three. ie.:

```
user 1 has olevel ticked
user 2 has olevel and alevel
user 3 has all three.
```

If I search with `olevel` checked, all three come up. If I search by `alevel`, only users 2 and 3 come up and so on.

I'm not quite sure where to begin on this. I am using php 5 and mysql. I'm not looking for people to write it for me, just looking to be pointed in the right direction.

Comment: A list of technologies isn't a good question title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you about something like this?

```
$conds=array('0');
if($needFindOlevel){
    $conds[]="olevel=1";
if($needFindAlevel){
    $conds[]="alevel=1";
if($needFindXlevel){
    $conds[]="xlevel=1";
$condition=implode(' OR ',$conds);


SELECT  FROM users WHERE $condition
```

Comment: Looks vaugly like it. Will have to write a quick test script. Do you think this will do a and/or or just an and?

Comment: Will take me a little time to work this into a script. A little bit of a newbee when it comes to this. Will let you know how IO get on.

Comment: Have worked it out. will post my code for others in the future.